# Dynamic VirtualDocumentRoot with Apache and dnsmasq

Tags: apache, dnsmasq

I am using **dnsmasq** and **Apache 2.2.24**,

so my `http-vhosts.conf` looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    VirtualDocumentRoot "/www/clients/%1"
    ServerAlias *.dev
    UseCanonicalName Off
</VirtualHost>
```

so that apache accesses `myclient.dev` like so:
`/www/clients/myclient/`

This works as expected, but if I want to use it like so:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    VirtualDocumentRoot "/www/clients/%1/%1.src"
    ServerAlias *.dev
    UseCanonicalName Off
</VirtualHost>
```

so that apache accesses `myclient.dev` like so:
`/www/clients/myclient/myclient.src`

The dot after the second `%1` seems to cause a problem, so there is no server response at all.

I tried to escape the dot with `\%1`, but then Apache tries to access the directory like so:

`/www/clients/myclient/myclient\\.src` and cannot access the directory, obviously.

Any ideas on how to make that work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is to specify "%N.0." so the first dot is not misinterpreted.